# iter ,range in for loop python

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, generator

I thought the "for in" statement takes in iterables not iterators, but somehow the following codes works fine. I am confused. Actually, I was looking at the generator example at :
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

```
>>> for i in range(10):
    print(i)


0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>> for i in iter(range(10)):
    print(i)


0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>>
```

Anyone can explain what happened when using iter(range(10)) in the for loop?

Comment: iterators *are iterables*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Iterators *are iterables too*. `for` calls `iter()` on the object it iterates over, and if you already have an iterator, then that produces a reference to the same object. This is by design.

From the [`iterator` entry in the Python glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator):

> Iterators are required to have an `__iter__()` method that returns the iterator object itself **so every iterator is also iterable** and may be used in most places where other iterables are accepted.

*Bold emphasis mine*.

From the same document, on the term [`iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable):

> When using iterables, it is usually not necessary to call `iter()` or deal with iterator objects yourself. The `for` statement does that automatically for you, creating a temporary unnamed variable to hold the iterator for the duration of the loop.

and from the [*Iterator types* section of the standard types document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter):

> The iterator objects themselves are required to support the following two methods, which together form the *iterator protocol*:
>
> ```
> iterator.__iter__()
> ```
>
> Return the iterator object itself. **This is required to allow both containers and iterators to be used with the `for` and `in` statements.**

*Bold emphasis mine*.

So when you use `for ... in iter(range(...))` instead of `for ... in range()`, you make an extra call to `iter()` that's basically redundant, as `for` already makes that call itself.

But you *can* use `iter()` *before* you use a `for` loop to keep a reference to the iterator; so you could use it to advance to the next value *elsewhere*, in coordination with the `for` loop:

```
>>> range_iter = iter(range(10))
>>> for i in range_iter:
...     print('for loop produced', i)
...     if i % 4 == 0:
...         j = next(range_iter)
...         print('But we can advance the iterator manually, too:', j)
...
for loop produced 0
But we can advance the iterator manually, too: 1
for loop produced 2
for loop produced 3
for loop produced 4
But we can advance the iterator manually, too: 5
for loop produced 6
for loop produced 7
for loop produced 8
But we can advance the iterator manually, too: 9
```

In the PEP, in the [detail section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/#the-details), the code example there uses an `iter()` call *before* calling the generator function, because that `iter()` call could potentially raise an exception. You'd want that exception to be raised when defining the generator expression, not later on when you try to iterate over the generator expression.

Or put concretely, the following code fails on the first line, not during looping:

```
gen = (x ** 2 for x in 1)  # 1 is not an iterable
for i in gen: print(i)
```

If the implementation did not call `iter()` *first*, then only when the `for` loop executes would there be an exception, and that would be confusing because the `gen` reference could have been created in any number of places in the code, really.

Comment: then why bother using iter(range(10)) in the generator example in the hyperlink?

Comment: @OpticalDataScience: because the PEP documents that the internal workings of the generator expression implementation will create an iterator *before* calling the generator function object. The actual implementation doesn't use a `for` loop, it generates bytecode that is roughly equivalent.

Comment: @OpticalDataScience: this matters when you use that generator expression at a later point in your code. If the `iter()` call fails, it'll fail at the point where the generator expression is defined, not where you eventually iterate over it.